# How do I find common characters in a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, function, intersect

I have about 70 dataframes in a list, each of them has a column named SNP. I want to find the common SNPs that exist in all dataframes. This is the code I used:

```
setwd("~")
library(data.table)

files <- list.files()
dflist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(files)){
 dflist[[i]] <- fread(files[i])
}

map(dflist, ~.$SNP) %>% 
reduce(intersect)
```

However, this returns the following message:

```
character(0)
```

```
list(structure(list(`10:103391446` = c("10:115562764:TTTC_",
"10:115562765:TTC_T", "10:14188623_CCTGA_C", "10:15988900:G_GGT"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(SNP = c("rs34394051",
"rs11121177", "rs10799615", "rs590013")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")),
    structure(list(SNP = c("rs34394051", "rs11121177", "rs10799615",
    "rs590013")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table",
    "data.frame")))
```

Can you help please?

Comment: it means you not have any common characters that common to all list element columns

Comment: For safety (and a little code-golf): `dflist <- lapply(setNames(nm=files), fread)`. BTW, you may also get `NULL` if `SNP` is not a column in *all* of them; if it is missing in one, it will kill the rest of your output.

Comment: I definitely have SNPs in common between the data frames. I just assumed the code is not working. Some SNPs (i.e. genetic variants) do not have a name and have the following format 1:234564. Can that interfere?

Comment: rkl, please [edit] your question and add some known context, perhaps the output from `dput(lapply(dflist[1:3], head, 4))` (assuming that that sampling has matches).

Comment: See my previous comment, and note that the column name in `dflist[[1]]` is `10:103391446`, not `SNP`. (It suggests that one of your files is not structured the same, having no column name(s) and very different-looking contents.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems appear to be two-fold:

1. One of your frames is missing `SNP` as a column name. That will often cause problems:

   ```r
   setdiff(mtcars$QUUX, mtcars$cyl)
   # NULL
   ```

   This is not hard to fix (`names(dflist[[1]]) <- "SNP"`), but does not resolve all of the problems.
2. Your first frame has completely different-looking data. When I skip the first frame, it works.

   ```r
   map(dflist[-1], ~.$SNP) %>%
     reduce(intersect)
   # [1] "rs34394051" "rs11121177" "rs10799615" "rs590013"
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much. When I read the files using dflist <- lapply(setNames(nm=files), fread), the SNP is the header for all data frames. Can you briefly explain why this happens and what the difference is in importing the files using these different ways?

Comment: The difference between `lapply` and a `for` loop are minor, some of it is stylistic. For both, I often suggest skimming through https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227 for a discussion on keeping frames in `list`s, though some of it (just the *concept* of it) you're already doing. I would not expect my code here to produce different column names than yours, I wonder if your `files` has a mixed bag of data structures (i.e., `"10:115562764:TTTC_"` vs `"rs34394051"`).

Comment: BTW, the use of `for (i in 1:length(files))` is a little fragile: when `files` is empty for some reason, while you might expect the `for` loop to do nothing, it will instead fire twice, because `1:length(.)` resolves to `1:0` resolves to `c(1L, 0L)`. It's better to use `seq_len(length(files))` or, better yet in this case, `seq_along(files)`. In both of those cases, a zero-length `files` will result in the `for` loop doing nothing, which is intuitively what should happen.

Comment: Hello, yes it does. The column contains  entries such as 10:115562764:TTTC_ and rs453.. When there is no rsid (i.e. name for the genetic variant), the data refers to it by its chromosome and position (i.e. 10:115562764).

Comment: Hi @r2evans is the code still OK if there are values such as these in (10:115562764:TTTC_ and rs453) in the column ? My final code is:                                ```
files <- list.files()
dflist <- lapply(setNames(nm=files), fread)
for(i in 1:length(files)){
 dflist[[i]] <- fread(files[i])
}

df<- map(dflist, ~.$SNP) %>% 
reduce(intersect)  %>%
as.data.frame()
```

Comment: The method I have here does not care if the strings start with `"rs"` or `"10:"` or anything else. The premise is looking for commonality.